# pygame rect collision smaller than image

Tags: python, image, pygame, collision, rect

How can I define a rect collision detection smaller than image in pygame?
I'd like to have a collision patter like the second image , but I'm having a cut image when a try to set the width and height in the method rect.

[image]

When I try to set using image size, I have the collision detection in red

```
    self.rect = pygame.rect.Rect(location, self.image.get_size())
```

If I set the size using width and height, I just have the third image

```
    self.rect = pygame.rect.Rect(location, (32, 150))
```

I really wouldn't like to use pixel perfect collision, because is the slowest collision detection, so someone have some idea how can I achieve the second image collision approach using Rect? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you are using pygames built in `sprite` module. (Please correct me if I am wrong)

You might know that each sprite consist of an **`image`** (which is drawn on a surface) and a **`rect` object** (sets location and size (!) of the `image`).

As Luke Taylor suggested, you could create a **new** `rect` object in your `player` class …

```
self.collideRect =  pygame.rect.Rect((0, 0), (32, 150))
```

… and set its location (according to your graphic) to

```
self.collideRect.midbottom = self.rect.midbottom
```

Every time you change the position of your `player` you must call this line too, so your `self.collideRect` rect object *"moves"* with your `player` on screen.

To test if a point (e.g. the mouse coordinates) is inside the `self.collideRect`, call

```
if self.collideRect.collidepoint(x, y) == True:
    print("You clicked on me!")
```

Comment: Nice recommendation, I realized that I was using the same rect to draw the image and to collide the objects. using a new rect and keep it linked with the image, i can have a better collision detection.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Try drawing a completely new rectangle separate from the image that is behind the image, but who's location is constantly set to that if the image.